# Lists and Files

Tags: java, list, file-io

How to write a list in a file using JAVA?

I am writing a program to search files in a directory and display it. I also have a condition that I should store the search result in a log file. So please help me doing this.

From comments:

```
public void saveSearchResult(List<String> SearchResult) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file1 = new File("D://result.log");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D://result.log");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file1);
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(in);
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(out);
    for (String search : getSearchResult()) {
        //Not getting hw to do this
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like something you could very easily do with a loop.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: public void saveSearchResult(List<String> SearchResult) throws FileNotFoundException{
  File file1=new File("D://result.log");
  FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream("D://result.log");
  FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file1);
  DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(in);
  DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(out);
  
  for(String search:getSearchResult()){
   //Not getting hw to do this

Comment: Above piece of code which i was trying to implement. I am nw learning the file stream concepts. Help me out.

Comment: You will want to post all code as an edit to your original question. Code does not format well in comments and is unreadable.

Comment: oh sorry.. New user too..

Comment: If you are a new user these 2 pages are very helpful. [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Place your results into a string. Then load it into the file as follows...

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
 for (String search : getSearchResult()) {
     s.append(search); //add formatting here as desired
    }

    try (FileWriter t = new FileWriter(new File("result.log"))) {
            t.write(s.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

You should always use a try with resources statement as above because it will insure the resources are released. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

For a growing string you should use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

You probably want to create multiple new log files in which case I would suggest replacing `"result.log"` with this following code

`new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss").format(new Date(
            System.currentTimeMillis())) + ".log"`

This will output your log files so it looks like this...

> result_2014-02-13_5-19-44.log
>
> year/month/day/hour/minute/second